# How to show the output of the following program in a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
numbers=[int(input("Number ( " + str(i+1) + " ) : ")) for i in range(int(input("How many numbers do you want to add ?")))]
for nums in numbers:
    new=[]
    if 10<nums and nums<100:
        new.append(nums)
        print(new)
```

if you insert 3 numbers like : 124 , 12 , 14
the answer will be :
[12]
[14]
but I want :
[12 , 14]
thank you :)

Comment: Create `new` before the loop. Print `new` after the loop.

Comment: Thank you do much :)

Comment: @Ali Welcome to SO. If you find an answer useful you may consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

```
numbers = [int(input("Number ( " + str(i + 1) + " ) : ")) for i in
           range(int(input("How many numbers do you want to add ?")))]

new = []  # This must be outside the loop
for nums in numbers:
    if 10 < nums < 100:
        new.append(nums)
print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're defining the `new = []` array inside the for loop, which is causing the creation of a new array every iteration.

Your code should look like this:

```js
numbers=[int(input("Number ( " + str(i+1) + " ) : ")) for i in range(int(input("How many numbers do you want to add ?")))]

new = []
for nums in numbers:
    if 10<nums and nums<100:
        new.append(nums)
print(new)
```